# Source code of usbmon

Tags: usb, kernel

Where can I get the source code of usbmon utility. Googling didn't help me to get the source code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It should be inside the kernel source packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of the kernel source, specifically the path is:

```
/drivers/usb/mon
```

You can browse the code online if you like, here is [an example from 4.4.8....](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/drivers/usb/mon?id=refs/tags/v4.4.8)